Azure DevOps PublishCodeCoverageResults@2 not generating Report
I have a Build Pipeline and I updated the PublishCodeCoverage Task to V2. When I run the pipeline, the Task runs successfully howeever after the pipeline finishes, a report is not generated and the following error is shown to me:

This is my Task:
  # Dotnet core sdk task 7.0.x (Pre-requisite for PublishCodeCoverageResults@2 task)
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 7.0.x'
    inputs:
      version: 7.0.x

  - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@2
    inputs:
      summaryFileLocation: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/coverage.xml"

and this is the output of the Task in the pipeline Run:

Has anyone tried the same? I dont understand what I am doing wrong :')

Aren't you supposed to add tasks to restore packages, build projects/solution and run tests (if any)?

yes, this task I am running in Unit Test Stage.

Have you created code coverage report before publish? Can you share your completed yaml file?

Not sure about your completed yaml. Below is my yaml for your reference. Use --collect "Code coverage" in the argument of DotNetCoreCLI@2 task when running test.
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '***'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
  
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '**/XUnit.Coverlet.Collector.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --collect "Code coverage"'

